# What to do if the private key was compromised?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, private-key

A hacker has entered my account. When I get some payment, it sends to another in 30 seconds. I need to get my tokens out of this wallet.. Is there any way? Is there any way I can change the private key? Or put some kind of password in the private key? I used this address for work I have many tokens in it.

Comment: How are things? Is it resolved

Comment: not when I send ethereum to transfer the tokens. the hacker. transfer to another wallet in 30 seconds

Comment: If you created a new private key and the same thing happened, then not only that is compromised. You didn't specify which wallet were you using or gave more details.

Comment: what do you mean by entered y account? are you using an online wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new wallet with a new private key. Transfer every token to this new wallet and you should be good.

Make a backup of the new private key!
NEVER share your private key with anyone! Not even your mother! :)

Comment: not when I send ethereum to transfer the tokens. the hacker. transfer to another wallet in 30 seconds